# Will the following code work to answer the question correctly?

Tags: c, unix

Write a C function that takes a filename as its parameter and returns true if the given file exists, is an ordinary file, and somebody has execute permission for it, and false otherwise.

```
int is_program(char *fname){
    struct stat sb;
    int res;

    res = stat(fname, &sb);

    if(res == 0)/*if file exists*/
    {
        if(S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGPR | S_IXOTH))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *fname` should be `const char *fname` because there's no reason to refuse constants. The rest is easy to test.

Comment: `if (res) return 0; /* Error, possibly doesn't exist */` would save from having to indent a major portion of your sub.

Comment: No need for the inner `if`. Simply use `return S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGPR | S_IXOTH);`

Comment: May wish to tag for your specific operating system (presumably some unix or variant).   Use of `stat()`, the various `S_` macros, and even the notion of "execute permission" are not part of standard C.

Answer (score 1):

No; what you've got won't do the job required.

You need to separate the test for a regular file:

```
ISREG(sb.st_mode)
```

from the test for executability:

```
(sb.st_mode & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH))
```

Hence you could use:

```
return (ret == 0) && ISREG(sb.st_mode) && (sb.st_mode & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH));
```

You might reasonably prefer to split it up:

```
if (ret != 0)
    return 0;
if (!ISREG(sb.st_mode))
    return 0;
return (sb.st_mode & (S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH));
```